# Retry on failure Firebase Function deploy failing using Github Action

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

I have a firebase function that is triggers on firestore doc OnCreate with `failurePolicy` set to `true` like so:

```
const webhookHandler = functions
  .runWith({
    failurePolicy: true,
    memory: '512MB',
    timeoutSeconds: 60,
  }).firestore.document(`${COLLECTIONS.eventsQueue}/{event_queue_id}`)
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

   //some code here...
})
```

Locally, using Firebase CLI i can deploy successfully, but requires I acknowledge that this function will retried on failure, do you still want to deploy? **Yes/No**.

once **Yes** is selected the function deploys successfully.

I'm using Github Actions to deploy the firebase functions automatically on PR merge. and Once i added the above function the github action deploy fails.

My assumption is that github action deploy is failing because the prompt.

My github deploy github action script does have `--non-interactive` and also tried with `--force`  and it keeps failing.

Seems the `--force` does not enforce on this function deploy locally or in github deploy. Any suggestions to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [yes](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yes.1.html) command included with most linux distros.

`yes | firebase deploy ...`

Answer (score 0):

credit to @nVitus helped solve this.

the exact script that solves it:

`yes | firebase deploy --only functions --force`